# Testing a function that uses enquo() for a NULL parameter

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function which creates dataframe, but changes names in the process. I am trying to handle empty column names with dplyr quosures. My test suite looks like this:

```
dataframe <- data_frame(
  a = 1:5,
  b = 6:10
)

my_fun <- function(df, col_name, new_var_name = NULL) {
  target <- enquo(col_name)

  c <- df %>% pull(!!target) * 3 # here may be more complex calculations

  # handling NULL name
  if (is.null(new_var_name)) {
    new_name <- quo(default_name)
  } else{
    new_name <- enquo(new_name)
  }

  data_frame(
    abc = df %>% pull(!!target),
    !!quo_name(new_name) := c
  )
}
```

And if I call my function like this:

```
my_fun(dataframe, a)
```

I get default name as intended:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
    abc default_name
  <int>        <dbl>
1     1            3
2     2            6
3     3            9
4     4           12
5     5           15
```

And if I'm trying to pass name I get error:

```
my_fun(dataframe, a, NEW_NAME)
Error in my_fun(dataframe, a, NEW_NAME) : object 'NEW_NAME' not found
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This problem doesn't really have to do with `quo` and `enquo` returning different things, it's really about evaluating objects before you really want to. If you were to use the `browser()` to step through your function, you'd see the error occurs at the `if (is.null(new_var_name))` statement.

When you do `is.null(new_var_name)`, you are evaluating the variable passed as `new_var_name` so it's too late to `enquo` it.  That's because `is.null` needs to look at the value of the variable rather than just the variable name itself.

A function that does not evaluate the parameter passed to the function but checks to see if it is there is `missing()`.

```
my_fun <- function(df, col_name, new_var_name=NULL) {
  target <- enquo(col_name)

  c <- df %>% pull(!!target) * 3 # here may be more complex calculations

  # handling NULL name
  if (missing(new_var_name)) {
    new_name <- "default_name"
  } else{
    new_name <- quo_name(enquo(new_var_name))
  }

  data_frame(
    abc = df %>% pull(!!target),
    !!new_name := c
  )
}
```

Then you can run both of these

```
my_fun(dataframe, a)
my_fun(dataframe, a, NEW_NAME)
```

Comment: Thank you!
This function was part of plotting function, and later I've got stuck on using quosures with ggplot. In current version `aes` doesn't support quosures, but I found out that ggplot have `aes_string`, which supports regular strings as arguments instead of formulas.

Answer (score 4):

The approach outlined by MrFlick does not work with nested function calls. We can use `rlang::quo_is_null` instead.

From the documentation on `rlang::quo_is_null` : "When missing arguments are captured as quosures, either through enquo() or quos(), they are returned as an empty quosure". So when we nest function calls with empty quosures, the call to `missing` in the inner function ends up checking whether an empty quosure is `NULL`, and always returns `FALSE` since it is the contents of the quosure that is `NULL` and not the quosure itself.

I put together the following verbose functions to show what is occurring:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

f1 <- function(var = NULL) {
    
    print(paste("substitute shows:", paste(substitute(var), collapse = " ")))
    print(paste("missing returns:", missing(var)))
    
    enquo_var <- enquo(var)
    print(paste("after enquo:", quo_get_expr(enquo_var)))
    print(paste("quo_is_null returns:", rlang::quo_is_null(enquo_var)))
    
    rlang::quo_is_null(enquo_var)
}

f2 <- function(var = NULL) {
    
    f1({{var}})
}

f1(Sepal.Length) 
f1() 

f2(Sepal.Length) 
f2() # this is where `missing` fails.
```

NB: I welcome corrections or additions to this explanation. Many thanks to mrflick, Lionel Henry, and Hugh. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66574591/check-if-object-is-null-or-undefined/66580483#66580483) for a related question.