# custom function not accepting arguments with rlang::enquo

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

I am writing a custom function which requires creating a data frame out of entered arguments. I want users to allow two different way to enter the arguments. As you can see below, one of the way is working, but not the one relying on `rlang`.

The idea is that I want to give as much flexibility to the function user as possible, therefore the optional argument and two different methods to enter the argument.

Here is a reproducible code:

```r
# loading libraries
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(datasets)

# preparing the dataset
iris <- datasets::iris
iris$newvar <- 1:length(iris$Sepal.Length)
str(iris)
#> 'data.frame':    150 obs. of  6 variables:
#>  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#>  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#>  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#>  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#>  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ newvar      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

# defining the custom function
myfun <- function(data = NULL, x, y, z = NULL) {
  if (!is.null(data)) {
    if (!is.null(z)) {
      data <-
        dplyr::select(
          .data = data,
          x = !!rlang::enquo(x),
          y = !!rlang::enquo(y),
          z = !!rlang::enquo(z)
        )
    } else {
      data <-
        dplyr::select(
          .data = data,
          x = !!rlang::enquo(x),
          y = !!rlang::enquo(y)
        )
    }
  } else {
    if (!is.null(z)) {
      data <-
        base::cbind.data.frame(x = x,
                               y = y,
                               z = z)
    } else {
      data <- base::cbind.data.frame(x = x,
                             y = y)
    }
  }

  print(str(data))

}

# method 1
# using the custom fuction without the optional argument
myfun(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Sepal.Length)
#> 'data.frame':    150 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ y: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#> NULL

# using the custom fuction with the optional argument
myfun(x = iris$Species, y = iris$Sepal.Length, z = iris$newvar)
#> 'data.frame':    150 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ y: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#>  $ z: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#> NULL

# method 2
# using the custom fuction without the optional argument
myfun(data = iris, x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)
#> 'data.frame':    150 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ y: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#> NULL
# using the custom fuction with the optional argument
myfun(data = iris,
      x = Species,
      y = Sepal.Length,
      z = newvar)
#> Error in myfun(data = iris, x = Species, y = Sepal.Length, z = newvar): object 'newvar' not found
```

Created on 2018-02-02 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48504942/2372064

Comment: @MrFlick YES!!! This solved the issue. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: @MrFlick How do I accept your answer? It doesn't show me any option to take your comment as the right answer.

Comment: Since it’s basically a duplicate. I can just close this question as a duplicate. You can upvote my answer on the other question if you like.

Comment: @MrFlick Done! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the test `!is.null(z))` is what is failing. It's attempting to interpret `z`, but `z` is set to the name `newvar` and and the `is.null` call can't interpret it, because there is no `newvar` object to be found.

Try this, instead:

```
!is.null(quo(z)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This does seem to solve the problem I am facing but creates a different problem. If I now enter: `myfun(data = iris, x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)`, it gives me the following error: `Error: NULL must resolve to integer column positions, not NULL`

Comment: Interesting problem. If you remove the NULL assignment for the`z` in the definition, the `myfun(data = iris, x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)` will work. But, then the other form of the call doesn't. Hmm.