# Optional argument programming with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm new to programming with `dplyr`. Let's say I have a function like this :

```
example <- function(data, group, var){

  group <- enquo(group)
  var <- enquo(var)

  data %>% 
    group_by(!! group) %>% 
    summarise(
      Min = min(!! var),
      Max = max(!! var)
    )  
} 

> diamonds %>% example(cut, price)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  cut         Min   Max
  <ord>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Fair        337 18574
2 Good        327 18788
3 Very Good   336 18818
4 Premium     326 18823
5 Ideal       326 18806
```

I'd like to add a new argument `sort`. If non specified, the function does nothing more, if specified the function does `arrange(desc(sort))`.

I tried things like this :

```
example <- function(data, group, var, sort = NULL){

  sort <- enquo(sort)
  group <- enquo(group)
  var <- enquo(var)

  data <- 
    data %>% 
    group_by(!! group) %>% 
    summarise(
      Min = min(!! var),
      Max = max(!! var)
    )

  if(is.null(sort)) data
  else arrange(data, desc(!! sort))

}
```

It works when the `sort` argument is specified

```
> diamonds %>% example(cut, price, sort = Min)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  cut         Min   Max
  <ord>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Fair        337 18574
2 Very Good   336 18818
3 Good        327 18788
4 Premium     326 18823
5 Ideal       326 18806
```

But if I'm leaving `sort` blank I get the error message :

> Error: cannot arrange column of class 'NULL' at position 1

How can I fix this ? Thanks for help and sorry for bad english

Comment: Move `sort <- enquo(sort)` to the _else_ part

Comment: @Haezer Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Moving `sort <- enquo(sort)` to the else section gets you closer, but you will still have a problem because the `if(is.null(sort))` line will return an error if you use `sort = Min` in the function because `is.null` will want to evaluate the `Min` object, but will not find it.

Instead of using `is.null`, you could use `missing`, which does not evaluate the `Min` object.

```
example <- function(data, group, var, sort = NULL){

  group <- enquo(group)
  var <- enquo(var)

  data <- 
    data %>% 
    group_by(!! group) %>% 
    summarise(
      Min = min(!! var),
      Max = max(!! var)
    )

  if(missing(sort)) {
    data
  } else { sort <- enquo(sort)
  arrange(data, desc(!! sort))
  }

}
```

Now we get the following outputs:

```
diamonds %>% example(cut, price)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  cut         Min   Max
  <ord>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Fair        337 18574
2 Good        327 18788
3 Very Good   336 18818
4 Premium     326 18823
5 Ideal       326 18806

diamonds %>% example(cut, price, sort = Min)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  cut         Min   Max
  <ord>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Fair        337 18574
2 Very Good   336 18818
3 Good        327 18788
4 Premium     326 18823
5 Ideal       326 18806
```

See [Testing a function that uses enquo() for a NULL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504942/testing-a-function-that-uses-enquo-for-a-null-parameter)