# Check if object is Null or undefined

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I have a function that includes an optional variable parameter. By default, I set the variable to `NULL`, but if it isn't `NULL` I'd like my function to do some stuff. I need a way to check if the variable is not null. This is complicated because I am using tidyeval, and just using `is.null(var)` throws an object not found error. I've found a hacky solution using `try`, but am hoping there's a better way.

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- data.frame(value = 1:8, 
                         char1 = c(rep("a", 4), rep("b", 4)), 
                         char2 = rep(c(rep("c", 2), rep("d", 2)), 2))

myfun <- function(dat, group = NULL, var = NULL) {
    
    x <- dat %>% 
        group_by({{group}}, {{var}}) %>% 
        summarize(mean = mean(value), 
                            .groups = "drop")
    
    # if(!is.null(var)) { # Throws object not found error if not null

    null_var <- try(is.null(var), silent = TRUE)
    null_var <- null_var == TRUE
    if(!null_var)   {
        print("do something with `var`")
    }
    x
}
myfun(dat)
myfun(dat, char1)
myfun(dat, char1, char2)
```

Comment: Check out `?exists `

Comment: Can you elaborate? `exists` seems to return FALSE whether `var = NULL` or `var = char2`. This is what I worked out so far: `tidy_exists <- function(x = NULL) { exists(deparse(substitute(x))) }; tidy_exists(); tidy_exists(char2)`. I am using `deparse(substitute))` since exists expects the variable name as a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504942/testing-a-function-that-uses-enquo-for-a-null-parameter

Comment: Also relevant: https://rpubs.com/tjmahr/quo_is_missing

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure if my question should stay up or not - the current guide to [programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) has replaced quosures with embrasures, and the question you linked is hard to find without looking for quosures specifically. My question could probably be rewritten to make it more generically accessible.

Comment: The embrace is a useful wrapper for the most common uses of quosures. If you want to do more advanced stuff, you’ll way to avoid the shortcut and use the more powerful primitive functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{` is the combination of `enquo()` and `!!` in one step. To inspect the contents of `var`, you need to decompose these two steps. `enquo()` defuses the argument and returns a quosure that you can inspect. `!!` injects the quosure into other calls.

Below we `enquo()` the argument at the start of the function. Inspect it with `quo_is_null()` (you could also use `quo_get_expr()` to see what's inside it). Then inject it inside `group_by()` with `!!`:

```
myfun <- function(dat, group = NULL, var = NULL) {
    var <- enquo(var)
    
    if (!quo_is_null(var)) {
        print("It works!")
    }

    # Use `!!` instead of `{{` because we have decomposed the
    # `enquo()` and `!!` steps that `{{` bundles
    dat %>% 
        group_by({{ group }}, !!var) %>% 
        summarize(mean = mean(value), .groups = "drop")
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lionel. This also works with nested function calls in a way that `missing` does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `is.null` to a symbol:

```r
dat <- data.frame(value = 1:8, 
                  char1 = c(rep("a", 4), rep("b", 4)), 
                  char2 = rep(c(rep("c", 2), rep("d", 2)), 2))
myfun <- function(dat, group = NULL, var = NULL) {
  if (is.null(substitute(var))) {
    print("var was NULL")
  } else {
    print("var was not NULL")
  }
}
myfun(dat)
#> [1] "var was NULL"
myfun(dat, char1)
#> [1] "var was NULL"
myfun(dat, char1, char2)
#> [1] "var was not NULL"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

If you just want to tell whether an argument was used, `missing` may be useful:

```r
dat <- data.frame(value = 1:8, 
                  char1 = c(rep("a", 4), rep("b", 4)), 
                  char2 = rep(c(rep("c", 2), rep("d", 2)), 2))
myfun2 <- function(dat, group = NULL, var = NULL) {
  if (missing(var)) {
    print("var was missing")
  } else {
    print("var was not missing")
  }
}
myfun2(dat)
#> [1] "var was missing"
myfun2(dat, char1)
#> [1] "var was missing"
myfun2(dat, char1, char2)
#> [1] "var was not missing"
```

Noting the following wrinkles:

```
myfun(dat, char1, NULL)
#> [1] "var was NULL"

## yet

myfun2(dat, char1, NULL)
#> [1] "var was not missing"

z <- NULL
myfun(dat, char1, z)
#> [1] "var was not NULL"
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It was working until I tried to nest the function inside another function and pass through the parameter. I've posted it as a [new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66580381/nesting-functions-with-null-parameter-and-enquo-embrasure)

Comment: This works but a more idiomatic and flexible solution for tidyeval code is to use `enquo()` and `!!` instead of `{{` when you need to inspect the defused variable.