# Nesting functions with NULL parameter and enquo/embrasure

Tags: r, dplyr

I am attempting to use a `tidyeval` style function with a NULL parameter. If that parameter is not NULL, then I need to change what the function does. I am now nesting the function inside another function, and the evaluation is no longer giving the desired result.

This is related to my [earlier question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66574591/check-if-object-is-null-or-undefined?noredirect=1#comment117696052_66574591) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48504942/testing-a-function-that-uses-enquo-for-a-null-parameter). However, I think it is distinct. I am struggling to understand what is happening exactly when I nest the function calls. When I step through in the debugger, I can see that within the top level function `var` has a value of `NULL` or `Sepal.Length`. However, within the second level function, var has the value of `{ { var } }`. This is always evaluating to not missing / not null. I'm trying to get to a solution where I can call `f1` as a stand alone function or use it within another function.

```
library(dplyr)

f1 <- function(var = NULL) {
    print(missing(var)) # testing both of these
    print(is.null(substitute(var)))
}

f1(Sepal.Length) # returns FALSE, as expected
f1() # returns TRUE, as expected 

f2 <- function(var = NULL) {

    f1({{var}})

}

f2(Sepal.Length) # returns FALSE, as expected 
f2() # ALSO returns FALSE - should return TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66580483/3373438). To paraphrase, `{{}}` combines `enquo` and `!!` in a single step, we can use `rlang::quo_is_null` to check if a quosure is null, but to do so need to separately quote and unquote the argument.

```
f1 <- function(var = NULL) {
    var <- enquo(var)
    print(rlang::quo_is_null(var))
}

f2 <- function(var = NULL) {

    f1({{var}})
}

f1(Sepal.Length) # FALSE
f1() # TRUE

f2(Sepal.Length) # FALSE
f2() # TRUE!
```